# most common value c++ using map

Tags: c++, dictionary

find the most common value (that with the highest frequency). If two (or more) values have the same frequency choose one of them at random

**I need help with the random bit**

```
    map<int, int > myp;
    int con = 0;
    for (int h = 0; h < distan.size(); h++) {

        con = (int) count(distan.begin(), distan.end(), distan[h]);
        myp.insert(pair<int, int> (con, distan[h]));
    }
    //getting the highest frequency value
    int max = 0;
    int temp_max = max;

    max = max_element(myp.begin(), myp.end())->first;
    cout<<con<<endl;
    data_labels.push_back(myp[max]);
    myp.clear();
```

Comment: `myp`, `con`, `distan` ... use *descriptive* names.

Answer (score 1):

I think random here means that you can choose any of them, not necessarily random. Anyway, with the current algorithm you would need to use `multimap` to store the counts as for the same number the `map` replaces the old value (the element from your input).

Additionally, the above solution isn't very effective. It basically traverses the input `n` times (where `n` is the number of input elements) and for each step it processes all the values again, i.e. the complexity is quadratic - `O(n*n)`.

The efficient way is to use the `map` to store the current count for every key (`O(n*log2(n))`) and at the end choose the key with max value (`O(n)`):

```
map<int, int> counts;
for (int h = 0; h < distan.size(); h++) {
    ++counts[distan[h]];
}

int max = -1;
int maxKey;
// or vector<int> maxKeys;
for (map<int, int>::const_iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
   if (it->second > max) {
       maxKey = it->first;
       max = it->second;
       // or maxKeys.reset(); maxKeys.push(it->first);
   }
   else if (it->second == max) {
       // you can maintain list of the inputs with max occurences here
       maxKeys.push(it->first);
   }
}
// in maxKey we have the key with max number of occurences
// in max we have the max number of occurences
// if max stays -1, maxKey will be invalid, i.e. input was empty
// or in maxKeys you can have list and choose random one
```